# Issue with running AssetBundleManager local server

Tags: unity-game-engine, server, unityscript, assetbundle

Everytime I try to run the local server on unity I get this error:

```
ArgumentException: Can't find process with ID 787
```

After this error, the button is disabled. I'm using a Mac, I'm running behind a proxy but my co-worker said that he can run it just fine. Maybe it's a bug? Once I click the error, it directs to this line of code in the LaunchAssetBundleServer script, which comes by default with the AssetBundleManager that you can download from unity.

```
var process = Process.GetProcessById (instance.m_ServerPID);
```

Comment: It is trying to get a process id that does not exist. That line of code should be in the `try{}catch(){}` block like the `KillRunningAssetBundleServer()` function but someone Unity missed to do this. This is what I think is happening, server cannot be created and therefore that process id is not present. Can you try it without proxy? Can you re-start your computer?If there is a server that is running on that port, it will be closed. Does your co-worker use Mac or PC?

Comment: Hmmm, unfortunately, no, I can't deactivate the proxy since it works for the whole company I work for. My Co-Worker is using a Mac to, which I found really weird.